# How to set accept in cell(2) after selecting in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have to set status as accept, reject for customer,while registering status while be pending. I need, if condition for this, which row is selected then corressponding event should change in database as accept or reject.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Testing", OIMS_01);
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    ad.Fill(ds);

    if (GridView1.SelectedRow != null)
    {
      ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text;
      ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1) = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text;
      ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2) = "Accept";

    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please select a row.')", true);
    }
    ad.Update(ds);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Your column name"] ="ACCEPT";
```

OR

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2] ="ACCEPT";
```

Comment: i am getting this error in Line 55:ad.Update(ds); Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Status"] ="ACCEPT";